# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Batsman' to data type int

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

This is my C# code - I am running the query

```
INSERT INTO PM
VALUES ('Ali', '6777777', '3', 'Batsman', 'Fine Player', 'njhuh8obj',     'Lahore');
```

It is running fine in the database, but not this.

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//button that add players
{
    // for picture to be uploaded
    string path = "~/Admin/Players"  FileUploadPicture.FileName;
    FileUploadPicture.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(path));

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO PM VALUES ( '" + TxtPlayerName.Text +    "','"+TxtPlayerType.Text + "','" + TxtPlayerBasePrice.Text + "','" + TxtPlayerRecord.Text + "',
'" + ddlCat.SelectedItem.Value + "','" + path + "','" + TxtPlayerAddress.Text + "')", con);//Query of my C# page

    // open connection with database
    con.Open();

    // Command for running query
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    // message shown after player is added
    Response.Write("<script>alert('**Player Added**')</script>");
}
```

It seems that there is a problem in code of my C# page not in database, but I am not sure about that.

So please help me to solve this out...

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Can you please write query for me..??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the second column of your database table accepts an integer value but you are passing a string (`TxtPlayerType.Text`). If you want to insert an entry with only values for select columns you must specify the column names as follows:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (Column1, Column2, ...) VALUES (Value1, Value2, ...)
```

When Column Names aren't specified you must pass values in the order they appear in the database table.

Answer (score 0):

Insert statement should follow the below format

```
Insert into <TableName>(Column1,Column2) Values (Value1,Value2)
```

It is good practice to define the column names in the statement as it make sure the order of the columns and also in future if new column added or deleted no need to change the code